# Missing namespace ServiceClient (ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web) using VS2013 with ServiceStack.Client package v.4.0.3

Tags: servicestack, visual-studio-2013

I'm fairly new to C#, Visual Studio, and totally new to ServiceStack.  I'm trying to create a ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.JsonServiceClient object, but I get the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ServiceClient' does not exist in the namespace
'ServiceStack' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have used the nuGet add-on's Library Package Manager to install the "Service Clients for ServiceStack" v4.0.3 package (id:ServiceStack.Client), verified that my target framerwork is ".NET Framework 4.5", and included

```
using ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web;
```

at the top of my code.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the just released [v4 of ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes) which is a **breaking release** with significant changes that requires additional development effort to upgrade to.

Here are [NuGet instructions to remain on ServiceStack V3](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3).

Comment: Is this a defect in v4, or is there a new method?

Comment: @cwm9 Please read [the release notes of v4 for details](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes), ServiceStack has undergone a significant refactor, e.g. the client libraries are now in the `ServiceStack.Client` NuGet package.

Comment: Oh, I see, REALLY significant changes.  Thanks, I thought I was going insane!

Comment: Oh God! Why didn't they update their documentation? https://servicestack.net/download That kills me.

Thank you for the answer - I can't believe ServiceStack broke their nuget packages, and just didn't worry about it!

Comment: They  informed users about the changes, almost 2 months ago. That the BSD version  3.9.71,  requires  a different procedure to download.  There are  a lot of SO questions about that.